# Нужны ли запятые в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в этом предложении:

*За успешные боевые действия в марте-апреле 1944 г. 749-й стрелковый полк был награждён орденом Красного Знамени.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом простом предложении (с одной грамматической основой) запятые не нужны. В нем **нет** ни причастных, ни деепричастных, ни сравнительных, ни уточняющих оборотов; второстепенные члены отвечают на **разные** вопросы: был награжден (чем?) орденом, (за что?) за действия, (когда?) в марте — апреле.

Но стоит отметить, что в сочетании *в марте — апреле* необходимо поставить не дефис, а тире.
Если сочетание имеет значение приблизительного указания, ставится дефис, например: ***в марте-апреле*** («то ли в марте, то ли в апреле»). Если же сочетание обозначает интервал значений («от... до»), ставится тире, пробелы нужны: [**в марте — апреле**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=285128) (т. е. с каких-то чисел марта до каких-то чисел апреля), ***в марте — мае*** (с марта до мая).

**За успешные боевые действия в марте — апреле 1944 г. 749-й стрелковый полк был награжден орденом Красного Знамени.**

*За успешные боевые действия по разгрому фашистских войск под Сталинградом приказом Наркома обороны от 1 марта 1943 г. 1-я артиллерийская дивизия была удостоена звания гвардейской* (с сайта Минобороны России). [без запятых]

*Более успешным было наступление в августе – сентябре в Галиции 8-й армии генерала А. А. Брусилова...* (История. Полный справочник для подготовки к ЕГЭ) [тире]

Comment: В такой конструкции тоже запятые не нужны?: Указом Президиума Верховного Совета СССР от 24.04.1944 г. за успешные боевые действия в марте — апреле 1944 г. 749-й стрелковый полк был награжден орденом Красного Знамени

Comment: Во избежание двусмысленности именно в этом предложении можно поставить запятые. Замечу, что если 1944 год в предложении присутствует, то второй раз дату лучше не писать. (Другое дело — 1942 или 1943 год.) Указом Президиума Верховного Совета СССР от 24.04.1944 г., за успешные боевые действия в марте — апреле, 749-й стрелковый полк был награжден орденом Красного Знамени.